# Using Maximum Likelihood Classification and raster border in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification, training

I have tried multiple times to see if this was an issue with my supervised classification, but I don't think it is. I created my training samples and created a signature file. Per my course, I need to run Maximum Likelihood. However, every time I do, my first class fills in extra border(s) around my results.

I am running ArcMap 10.3. I have attached an image of my Landsat5 imagery before I ran the Maximum Likelihood classification, as well as after (which is the issue I am having). If I had to guess, this is something very simple I missed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your original image is actually the size of the filled-borders output that you think is an error. Set your original tiff to display NaNs as a color (rather than transparent) and see what happens.

Comment: And it was something simple I missed.. Any advice on how to remove that all together on my original tiff?

Comment: @RRodgers, rather than asking a new question in the comments, I suggest you [edit] your question and rephrase it. This will ensure more people see the question and give you a good answer.

Comment: @RRodgers I think the easiest way would be to hand-draw a polygon and clip your tiff with that polygon. That way you can also get rid of the "fuzzy" edges of the actual image and the gray stripe on the right side.